# Textarea overflows dialog when offering bounty on a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

I just tried to add a bounty to a question and observed the following:

[image]

Basically, as I started typing, the textarea expanded and pushed everything leftward in the dialog, with some of it being clipped. The words that appear as `(oere` and `wiease` are actually `There` and `Please`, and can be observed if I scroll back - it's very strange.

Browser is Firefox 19.0.2 on Windows 7 64-bit - does anyone else observe this?

Comment: [Reproduced](http://prntscr.com/zzftm): Firefox 19 (Pale Moon), Win7 64-bit.